# Access Properties from "Parent" Class

Tags: c#, properties

I have a `Course` class that contains list of students and a passing grade for that course.

```
public class Course
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public float PassingGrade { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, after the student finished their course, we calculate the final grade. But how do we get the passing grade for each of the students?

One of my approaches is to make a `PassingGrade` property inside the `Student` class and use the following code inside the `Course` class

```
public float PassingGrade
{
    get => _passingGrade;
    set
    {
        foreach (Student student in Students)
            student.PassingGrade = value;

        _passingGrade = value;
    }
}
```

I think my approach is not an elegant one (neither an appropriate way). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The passing grade is a property of the course, not the student, so don't assign it to the student. You haven't shown the code where you calculate the passing grade, so it's hard to give specifics, but it should be possible to take the value of the passing grade from the course and pass it to wherever it's required

Comment: @canton7, yeah, I have a `Pass` (bool) property inside `Student` class which is true when the student reaches that passing grade

Comment: Do you want different passing grades for different student? or do you want passing grade same for all students but different for different courses? If your answer is yes for second question then you have correct model definition.

Comment: I'd suggest you give both IDs. As is, one Student could only ever attend one Class. But you probably want them to attend a bunch. So, you have Students, Classes, each of which have IDs. Now you can collect _in a separate DataStructure_ what Student had what Grade for what Class and then you can calculate the final Grade and compare it to the Passing Threshold of the respective class. And then you'd store that result somewhere else ... Maybe a List of some class that holds a StudentID, ClassID, some indication of the semester, the grade, the passing grade thresh. , ...